# Segmented Logistic Regression - how do you contrast segments?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I have a dataset with individual level data showing 1) whether or not an outcome occurred, and 2) the date of the event. During data collection, there were two discrete interventions at specific timepoints (I'll refer to these points as i1 and i2).  I want to determine:

1) if there was a change in the slope during the time between i1 and i2 (segment 2) compared to the time before i1 (segment 1)

2) if there was a change in slope between i2 and the end of data collection (segment 3), compared to i1 and i2 (segment 2).

My model is as follows:

```
glm(data = mydata, outcome = (post + i1_i2_ + pre)*(1+datevariable), family = "binomial")
```

post = a binary variable stating whether or not the date occurred after i2

i1_i2 = binary variable stating whether or not the date occurred after i1 but before i2

pre = stating whether or not the date occurred before i1 (reference category)

datevariable = numeric variable indicating the number of days since the first day of data collection

What is the appropriate way to compare the slope of segment 3 vs segment 2, without changing the reference category from segment 1?

Comment: With no data to support a coding answer, this looks like a statistical question where you need help figuring out how to frame a question and do the proper search to find information about linear constrasts. Voting to migrate to CrossValidated.com. I could probably stumble through an explanation but first I would need a dataset to work with and you have fallen down in your responsibility to provide a [MCVE]